# Windows suddenly and unexpectedly hibernates after a minute or two

Tags: windows, hibernate

Not a heating issue, apparently (fans are spinning, it sits on a cold surface in cold room).

It does not just power-off suddenly; rather it suddenly switches to the blue windows "Locking..." screen and then hibernates. (Powers off normally, like it thinks I told it to hibernate, then I can power it on again, and it comes out of hibernation, just like when hibernating normally).

It can sit in the BIOS screen for hours, so seems more like a windows or software issue, than a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

It was the battery.

(This PC is an old laptop on it's second battery, a 3rd party one).

The sudden unexpected hibernation did not occur after removing the battery and running with just the power connected. Reconnecting the battery and running again brought back this sudden unexpected hibernation problem.

A failure of some kind in the battery that causes abnormal temperature or voltage, resulting in windows hibernating for safety, is a good bet.